# SQL - Outputting Averages Satisfaction/Count of Promotions within brackets of score range

Tags: sql

So far i have developed a query to output counts of each employee within score ranges (Evaluation scores hence from evaluation table). I am struggling to figure out how to perform mathematical functions on these ranges of employees outputted. It will be necessary to pull information from my Employee table to count numbers promotedinlast5years/not and also satisfaction levels. Find attached below the query regarding ranges.

```
SELECT t.range AS [0-1], count(Employee_ID) AS [Number of Employees]
FROM (
SELECT CASE 
WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 0.25 THEN ‘0-0.25’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.5 THEN ‘0.25-0.5’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.75 THEN ‘0.5-0.75’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.75 AND 1 THEN ‘0.75-1’
FROM Evaluation)
GROUP BY t.range;
```

Comment: Your derived table (subquery) returns 1 column (unnamed), but then you suddenly have 2 columns at top level.

Comment: your case statement is missing an 'end'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 0.25 THEN ‘0-0.25’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.5 THEN ‘0.25-0.5’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.75 THEN ‘0.5-0.75’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.75 AND 1 THEN ‘0.75-1’ end AS range,
count(Employee_ID) AS [Number of Employees]
FROM Evaluation 
GROUP BY CASE 
WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 0.25 THEN ‘0-0.25’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.5 THEN ‘0.25-0.5’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.75 THEN ‘0.5-0.75’
WHEN score BETWEEN 0.75 AND 1 THEN ‘0.75-1’ end
```

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a subquery, so keep on using it.  You just need proper aliases:

```
SELECT e.range AS [0-1], count(*) AS [Number of Employees]
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 0.25 THEN '0-0.25'
                   WHEN score BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.5 THEN '0.25-0.5'
                   WHEN score BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.75 THEN '0.5-0.75'
                   WHEN score BETWEEN 0.75 AND 1 THEN '0.75-1'
              END) as range
      FROM Evaluation
     ) e
GROUP BY e.range;
```

Notes:

- The subquery needs an alias.  I used "e" for "evaluation".
- The curly single quotes need to be straight single quotes (that might be a cut-and-paste issue).
- `EmployeeId` is not defined in the outer query.  I think `COUNT(*)` is probably equivalent.